# TypeError: ws.onopen is not a function in stomp-node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stomp

I need to use nodejs to run a stomp client for javascript and send stomp message over websocket.

I have a js file send.js:

```
var Stomp = require('stompjs');
var client = Stomp.overWS('ws://localhost:61614');
```

I ran `node send.js` in command line but got below errors:

> /xxx/node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js:71
>         ws.onopen();
>        ^
>   TypeError: ws.onopen is not a function
>       at WebSocketClient. (/xxx/node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js:71:10)
>       at WebSocketClient.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at WebSocketClient.succeedHandshake (/xxx/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:335:10)
>       at WebSocketClient.validateHandshake (/xxx/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:319:10)
>       at ClientRequest.handleRequestUpgrade (/xxx/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:248:14)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:476:11)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)

Why? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`stompjs` links to [this Github page](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket) which states that *"This project is no longer maintained"*.

It was last updated about 4 years ago.

I think you should consider a more up-to-date alternative like [`@stomp/stompjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stomp/stompjs)